# Commas in replaceText (Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm writing a script that take an arrays of values in Google Spreadsheet and populate a Google Docs. Everything is working using body.replaceText. 
The only issues is that the text in the Google Doc appears with a comma at the end.

So if I have

```
%AREA_2%    text here
%AREA_3%    text here
%AREA_4%    text here
```

In the Docs appears:  `text here,` (with the comma)

```js
var tag = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
var content = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues(); 
for (var i in tag){
  body.replaceText(tag[i], content[i]+"");
}
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to avoid it?
Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that the Google Docs API is grabbing the values from the spreadsheet like it would from a CSV file and not getting rid of the commas between values. For this you would want to iterate through your `content` variable and create a string manually by appending the values of the cells to a master string.

Answer (score 1):

You are (mis)using the `getValues()` method, which will return a two-dimensional array (rows of cells). If we pause execution inside the `for` loop, here's what we have in memory:

[image: debugger]

Note that `tag` and `content` are arrays-of-arrays. The three sub-arrays in `tag` each have one element, while those in `content` have two.

So in this line...

```js
body.replaceText(tag[i], content[i]+"");
```

...we have a method that is expecting two String parameters. The Javascript engine attempts (and succeeds) at providing them, even though neither `tag[i]` nor `content[i]` are Strings to start with. This is called [*type coercion*](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-type-coercion-data-types--cms-21913).

The case of `tag[0]` is very simple; the single element array gets interpreted as a string, with no noticeable side-effects.

What about `content[0]`? It's a two-element array, containing `"text here"` and `""`, a blank string. The array is *coerced* by joining its elements together, separated by commas. So that's why you see `text here,`. (You would get the same result with [`content[i].join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).)

A quick fix would be to correct the indices being used to read `content`:

```js
var content = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); 
                                                      ^^^
```

Alternatively, we could ensure the code matches the data structure, and avoid relying on coercion altogether:

```js
var tag = 0, content = 1; // Column indices
var tagset = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
for (var i in tagset){
  body.replaceText(tagset[i][tag], tagset[i][content]+"");
}
```